# How do I add iPadOS pointer interactions to web content?

Tags: css, ios, wkwebview, uipointerinteraction

I work on an e-reader app that uses WKWebView to display text content from ePubs. How do I customize pointer behavior on iPadOS 13.4 and later in my web content? I'd love to be able to get highlight effects on arbitrary anchor tags! Are there CSS properties that affect this, similar to the existing pointer styles?

Answer (score 1):

Can't say for sure, but the best standard for them to have leveraged would be PointerEvent. https://caniuse.com/#search=Pointer%20Event

Unclear how that would relate to the CSS and hover states, though.